# $(...).jstree(...).get_node is not a function

Tags: jquery, meteor, jstree

I get the following error on console:

```
TypeError: $(...).jstree(...).get_node is not a function
```

Following is the code (javascript file)

```
setPathToRootFromSelected = function(node) {
if (node == undefined) return;
var nodeParents = node.parents.slice();
var pathToRootFromSelectedIds = (nodeParents.reverse())
    .slice(1);
pathToRootFromSelectedIds.push(node.id);

var pathToRootFromSelected = _.map(pathToRootFromSelectedIds, function(nodeId) {
    console.log('check21');
    if (node.original.treeType == "browseByTopic")
        return $('#topic-tree')
            .jstree()
            .get_node(nodeId);
    else if (node.original.treeType == "practiceAndTest")
        return $('#practice-and-test')
            .jstree()
            .get_node(nodeId);
    else
        return $('#course-tree')
            .jstree()
            .get_node(nodeId);
});

return pathToRootFromSelected
```

};

I am using meteor. I have included jss:jstree package. Also included jquery, jss through html files.

Please enlighten as why does it happen.

Apologies if language isn't very clear :P